# How to use visusal c++ 2010 to access access database?

Tags: visual-c++, ms-access, ado

I am facing the problem to access database,how can i use ado to access access database?
i am using visusal c++ 2010 and access 2003

can anyone tell me to the simple procedure for this ?
thank you

Comment: Can we get this man a `masochist` badge?!

Comment: Microsoft access can be setup as an ODBC data source, generally that is the easiest way to interact.

Comment: Wouldn't ADO classic be the more natural fit here?

Answer (score 0):

No, because there is no "simple" procedure.

There is an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff965871.aspx#DataProgrammingWithAccess2010_ADOExample although you might need to change the version numbers to use Access 2003.  That page also has a bunch of information about other database APIs, some of which may be easier to use from C++.  And by *easier*, I mean *tearing-your-hair-out difficult* instead of *jumping-off-a-cliff difficult*.